# Word-VBA: apply shading in specific Range?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I create a function for finding a text in a range of document and apply a shading on the text if found.
I running the code as follow, but it will find whole document text and apply a shading.

The document like :
[image]

How to make the function work? Thanks!

```
Public Function myFun_findTxt2addShading( _
            str_findTxt As String, _
            range_myRange, _
            str_repTxt As String, _
            str_ShadingColor As String) As Boolean

Dim boolean_checkFound As Boolean
boolean_checkFound = False

range_myRange.Select
With Selection
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Text = str_findTxt
    .Find.Replacement.Text = str_repTxt
    .Find.Forward = True
    .Find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = str_RepFontColor
    .Find.Wrap = wdFindStop
    Do While .Find.Execute
        Selection.Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
        Selection.Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = str_ShadingColor
        boolean_check = True
    Loop
    .Find.Format = False
    .Find.MatchCase = False
    .Find.MatchWholeWord = False
    .Find.MatchByte = False
    .Find.MatchWildcards = False
    .Find.MatchSoundsLike = False
    .Find.MatchAllWordForms = False

End With
findTxt_Shading = boolean_checkFound
End Function

Sub test()
With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    .Find.Execute findText:="bookmark1", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="sybStart"
    .Find.Execute findText:="bookmark2", Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
     ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="sybEnd"
End With
Set sybRange = ActiveDocument.Range
sybRange.Start = sybRange.Bookmarks("sybStart").Range.End
sybRange.End = sybRange.Bookmarks("sybEnd").Range.Start

a = myFun_findTxt2addShading("pp", sybRange, "pp", wdColorYellow)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the `Selection.Range` you're giving it? Does it represent the specific `Selection` you mean to work with? Please [edit] your post to fill in the blanks, there's currently not enough information to make a good [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself some favors.

1. Put 'option explicit' at the top of each module.
2. In the VBA IDE go Tools.Options.Editor and make sure all the boxes in the Code Settings group are ticked.
3. In the VBA IDE, placing the cursor on a Keyword and pressing F1 brings up the MS help page for that keyword.  Try it for the .Find method.

I tidied up your code a little and used more sensible naming (only a little more sensible).  The code below will now highlight each word in the selection in the document.

Please note that I have deliberately used two with groupings so that you can take other actions each time the findTxt is found.  If you just wanted to highlight the text you could omit the second With group and change .Format from False to True.

```
Public Function AddShadingToFoundText( _
            findTxt As String, _
            repTxt As String, _
            ShadingColor As WdColor) As Boolean

    Dim findTxtFound As Boolean

    findTxtFound = False

    If myRange.Characters.Count < Len(findTxt) Then
        ' No point in searching if the selected text is
        ' smaller than the search text.
        Exit Function

    End if

    With myRange.Duplicate
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = findTxt
            .Replacement.Text = findTxt
            .Forward = True
            ' str_RepFontColor
            '.Find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = str_RepFontColor
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute

        End With

        ' Make sure there is still room for the search text
        Do While .Find.Found And .Start < myRange.End - Len(findTxt)
            .Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
            .Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorAutomatic
            .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = ShadingColor
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            .Move unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            .Find.Execute
            findTxtFound = True

        Loop

    End With

    AddShadingToFoundText = findTxtFound

End Function

Sub test()
Dim a As Boolean
a = AddShadingToFoundText("row", Selection.Range, "row", WdColor.wdColorRed)

End Sub
```